# NSTextField keep caret position on up_key_pressed

Tags: cocoa

In NSTextField: when up_key is pressed the cursor position goes to begin of text in NSTextField. But I need to keep the cursor position. It doesn't go to begin.

I try to use this code:

```
-(void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [[myTextField currentEditor] moveToEndOfLine:nil];
}
```

but via this code I can see that the cursor position goes to begin end then goes to end.

is any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution:

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)command
{
    if( [NSStringFromSelector(command) isEqualToString:@"moveUp:"] )
    {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```